# Sorting files in alphabetical order

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of **files** like this :

```
['../page-1.png', '../page-3/png', '../page-2.png', '../page-6.png',  ... '../page-9.png']
```

I need to sort these files according to the number at the end. I am using this :

```
imagePaths.sort((a, b) =>
        a.toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toString().toLowerCase()));
```

where `imagePaths` is the list of paths of those images.

**THE ISSUE**
This method works fine until there are only single digit file numbers, i.e. if there is a file called, `'../page-10.png'`, it gets sorted into the list like so :

`['../page-1.png', '../page-10.png', '../page-11.png', '../page-12.png', '../page-2.png', ..]`

Now, how to sort them in their correct order?

Comment: @jamesdlin it's similar but the numbers are at the end in my question. I will try one of the solutions suggested bellow

Comment: The position of the numbers is different, but it's the same underlying problem. `compareNatural` should still work for your case, or you should be able to adapt The parsing code from the linked answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I could give you an idea.
If the name pattern remains the same, then this gonna work out!

```
  var pages = [
    '../page-1.png',
    '../page-2.png',
    '../page-11.png',
    '../page-12.png',
    '../page-10.png',
  ];

  pages.sort((a, b) =>
      int.parse(a.split('-')[1].split('.')[0]).compareTo(int.parse(b.split('-')[1].split('.')[0])));
  
  print(pages);

//   [../page-1.png, ../page-2.png, ../page-10.png, ../page-11.png, ../page-12.png]
```

Just splitting the string and parsing the number and then sorting it.

Reference: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Pattern-class.html

Hope that works!

Comment: Yup! It works .

Answer (score 1):

A clean and safe solution will be by using a regex to extract the numbers instead of relying on the name format:

```
int parse(String page) {
   return int.tryParse(page.split(RegExp(r'[^\d]')).singleWhere((value) => int.tryParse(value) != null));
}

list.sort((a, b) => parse(a) > parse(b) ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: I tried this, and got an error, "bad state: too many elements". This error was thrown at ".singleWhere". I'm sorry, but I keep forgetting how to use regex

Comment: That happens because you probably have multiple numbers then. Can you provide me with the list that gave you the error?

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple numbers, the list is given in the question, in "THE ISSUE"

Answer (score 1):

Whist there are technical solutions to this, as per the other answers, the fundamental problem is that the files are not being named correctly if the intention is to sort them by name at some point. The numeric portion of the name should be given sufficient  leading zeroes to handle the maximum number of files eg. page-0001.png, page-0002.png, etc.

Comment: I thought of this first, but the problem is that these files have already been created in the user's device, amd they are NOT images. I just showed the files as images for security reasons. The possible solution for me is one of the suggested solutions, but thanks!